# How can i memoize a value of `useSelector()`?

Tags: redux, css-selectors, redux-toolkit

My code looks something like this:

```
const countersSelector = () => (store) => store.counters;

const MethodOne = () => {
  // Method: Object destructuring
  const counters = useSelector(countersSelector);

  console.log("render MethodOne");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("in useeffect methodone");
  }, [counters]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{`firstCounter: ${counters}`}</p>
      <p>{`renders: ${renderCount}`}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MethodOne;
```

This is the full app:
https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-useselector-object-destructuring-example-forked-1m87x

And every time `counters` object is changed (not its value, but the object reference itself), that `useEffect()` gets triggered.

Can i memoize it somehow, so that `counters` will only change if the actual values of `store.counters` change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking for here.

`state.counters` changing to a new object reference is how immutable updates work. [Immutable updates *always* require updating _all nested fields](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#updating-nested-objects).  So, if the action is supposed to update `rootState.counters.firstCounter`, it requires creating a new object for `counters` and a new object for `rootState`.

So, if your selector is `state => state.counters`, then `useSelector` *will* re-render the component every time the `counters` object changes to a new reference, `useEffect` will re-run because there is a new reference inside its dependencies array, and *that is exactly how this is supposed to work*.

As a side note, your `countersSelector` is incorrect.  It's written as a "factory function" that *returns* a selector.  That means that `useSelector` will actually be looking at *the new function reference*, not *the value extracted from state*.

Instead, it should just be `state => state.counters`.